# How do I do an Inner Join with 2 On Clauses, sort of like this

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
update table1 inner join
       table2
       on table1.part_no = table2.partno
       on table1.part_des = table2.partdes
    set table1.description = table2.description;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `and`:

```
update table1 inner join
       table2
       on table1.part_no = table2.partno and
          table1.part_des = table2.partdes
    set table1.description = table2.description;
```

You can also use a correlated subquery:

```
update table1
    set description = (select table2.description
                       from table2
                       where table1.part_no = table2.partno and
                             table1.part_des = table2.partdes
                      );
```

Comment: With this it says: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ".

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 inner join
       table2
       on table1.part_no = table2.partno
       and table1.part_des = table2.partdes
    set table1.description = table2.description;
```

Comment: There was a typo. I have edited my answer and checked it. It's working. Please check whether column names are correct in the query.